# SSH example does not work with docker:git / dind image

Tags: gitlab

I'm reading the documentation: https://gitlab.ida.liu.se/help/ci/ssh_keys/README.md

I'm using the current gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:git
services:
- docker:dind
stages:
- node_test
- docker_one
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
before_script:
  # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
  # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
  # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
  # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com | sort -u - ~/.ssh/known_hosts -o ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - '[[ -f /.dockerinit ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
node_test:
  image: node:7.3.0
  stage: node_test
  script:
    - ls
docker_one:
  stage: docker_one
  script:
    - docker info
```

node_test passes:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Docker executor with image node:7.3.0 ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image node:7.3.0 ...
Running on runner-4e4528ca-project-2641294-concurrent-0 via runner-4e4528ca-machine-1487244621-a8ff6b11-digital-ocean-4gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/instanty/test'...
Checking out 0b261283 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (rsa w/o comment)
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 11
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
$ ssh-keyscan gitlab.com | sort -u - ~/.ssh/known_hosts -o ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
$ [[ -f /.dockerinit ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ls
Build succeeded
```

It fails when I use the image docker:git and service dind:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Docker executor with image docker:git ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image docker:git ...
Running on runner-4e4528ca-project-2641294-concurrent-0 via runner-4e4528ca-machine-1487244733-2b616928-digital-ocean-4gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/instanty/test'...
Checking out 0b261283 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 14
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
/bin/sh: eval: line 50: syntax error: unexpected "("
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 2
```

Why does this image fail?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is not recognized by the shell used by your image :
`ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")`

ssh-add takes a file as an argument. So to fix this, you can replace this line with :

> echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ssh.priv
>   ssh-add ssh.priv